# how to file get with base url in laravel 8 using relation

Tags: php, laravel

```
$data = Course::with('subject' , 'module' , 'lession' ,'lecture_audio' , 'lecture_text', 'lecture_document', 'lecture_image' ,'lecture_other_video' , 'course_video' , 'video' ,'add_assessment' , 'add_homework','text_homework' , 'video_homework')->where('id' , $request->course_id)->get();
return $data;
```

Comment: my issuse is 1663593257.jpg     butt i,want file  http://127.0.0.1:8000/images/1663592168.jpg

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

you can simply add this function in each model that has a file

```
public function getImageAttribute($value){
    return asset('images' . $value);
}
```

then you replace the images word in the asset with the path you want, and change the Image in `getImageAttribute` with the column name, and if it's something like `user_image` you make it `getUserImageAttribute`